# $_POST undefined index PHP error

Tags: php, html

My html code which receives the string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="Segoe UI" siz ="3">
    <form action="process.php" action="post">
    Suggestion: <input type="text" name="sgst" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP which processes it: (process.php)

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["sgst"]=="john") {
        echo "john";
    } else {
        echo "someone";
    }
?>
```

I am getting the error

> Notice: Undefined index: sgst in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\process.php on line 2

Can anyone tell me what is causing the error?

Comment: You are actually posting the form right?

Comment: in your form attribute please use method="post" instead of action="post".

Comment: It means no value was passed in. PHP notices can generally be ignored unless you're having other problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined index with $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809937/undefined-index-with-post)

Comment: @hardiksolanki
Yea, it was a typo. Probably result of not having sleep last night. Thank you! :D

Comment: @andrew oh hey that's one of my first questions, but yea hardiksolanki is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using the `action` attribute on the `form` element:

```
<form action="process.php" action="post">
```

I'm surprised the form is even posting at all given that.  Though given the symptoms it seems to at least be enough to confuse the POST.  I think you meant to use the `method` attribute:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```

A couple other notes:

- You'll want to make use of `isset()` in your server-side code.  The code shouldn't assume that all values will be posted, since the server can't control what a client sends it.  Best to explicitly validate the data coming in before using it.
- `font` elements are pretty dated, and if they're not officially deprecated they should be :)  CSS styling would be the way to go for client-side UI styles.

Answer (score 1):

use isset

```
if(isset($_POST["sgst"]=="john")){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**it shows undefined because at first the value is not initialized**

use `isset()` inorder to check for value declared or not then it wont show error...

**try this i have changed**

```
<?PHP 
if (isset($_POST["sgst"])
{
   if ($_POST["sgst"]=="john") {
    echo "john";
   } else {
    echo "someone";
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: No matter what name I enter now, it always says "someone".

Comment: try this i have changed

Answer (score 0):

Try following

use Method attribute like `method="post"`in form tag instead of `action="post"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="Segoe UI" siz ="3">
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    Suggestion: <input type="text" name="sgst" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</font>
</body>
</html>    


 if (isset($_POST["sgst"]) && $_POST["sgst"]=="john") {
            echo "john";
        } else {
            echo "someone";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing method attribute.

Using two forms- Remove first form.

Try this,

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

 <?php
        if(!empty($_POST)){
        if ($_POST["sgst"]=="john") {
                echo "john";
            } else {
                echo "someone";
            }
        }
        ?>
```