# Undefined index $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, pdo

I am working on an authentication form, and this is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="matriculeAgent" placeholder="Compte matriculaire">

<input type="password" class="form-control password" name="motdepasseAgent" placeholder="mot de passe">
```

This is the PHP code where I compare the `matriculeAgent` and `motdepasseAgent` with the information of the database:

```
$matricule_verif = $_POST["matriculeAgent"] ; 
//password: 
$motdepasse_verif = $_POST["motdepasseAgent"] ; 
if ((isset($_POST["matriculeAgent"])==true) && (isset($_POST["motdepasseAgent"])==true)){
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT `matriculeAgent`, `motdepasseAgent` FROM `utilisateurs` WHERE `matriculeAgent` ='".$matricule_verif.'"AND `motdepasseAgent` = "'.$motdepasse_verif."'");
  // SI AUCUN ENREGISTREMENT NE CORRESPOND 
if(mysql_num_rows($req)==0) 
{ 
echo "Aucun utilisateurs ayant le mot de passe saisi existe. Reéssayer"; 
} 


// SI LE LOGIN ET MOT DE PASSE SONT EXACTES 
else 
{ 
    $_SESSION['matriculeAgent'] = $row['matriculeAgent'];
    $_SESSION['motdepasseAgent'] = $row['motdepasseAgent'];
// REDIRECTION VERS UNE PAGE PROTEGEE 
header("Location:accueil.php");
// selection de lenregistrement saisie a la page login.php 
}

}
else{

    echo "veuillez saisir le motdpass";
}
```

This are the errors I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: matriculeAgent in C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\esmcm\dossier\makeLogin.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: motdepasseAgent in C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\esmcm\dossier\makeLogin.php on line 27

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339949/post-undefined-index-php-error?s=5|2.4276 and many others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like $row['matriculeAgent'] is not set. this could be caused by multiple causes. I noticed several problems in your code, which I try to explain here.

first of all, if you want to you [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp), dont include your parameters directly inside the stmt->prepare() function call, use bind-param instead:

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT `matriculeAgent`, `motdepasseAgent` FROM `utilisateurs` WHERE `matriculeAgent` = ? AND `motdepasseAgent` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $matricule_verif, $motdepasse_verif);
```

then, another problem may be that you did not execute the statement, or you didn't show it in the post.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

after that, you can simply fetch your results, it should then be correctly populated:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

another way after execute(): as you are already using prepared statements, you could use here also bind_result(), which will populate your desired variables:

```
$varA = '';
$varB = '';
$stmt->bind_result($varA, $varB);
$stmt->fetch();
```