# what is unsupported grant type error in swift?

Tags: swift, post, networking, nsurlsession

I'm trying to make a simple login post request with URLSession with my userDetails object as input and request is of content type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, in response i am supposed to get an object of "access token", `"refresh token"`, `"userdetails"`.
but i keep getting:

> error = "unsupported_grant_type"

request on postman works but something is not right when I make a request in my project. what am i doing wrong here?? API team says the input object has to be correct which is exactly from the postman.

```
func loginUser() {
    /// login request here
    
    let url = URL(string: EndPoint.loginUser)!
            
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let userData: [String: Any] = [
        "UserName": "myUserEmail",
        "Password": "myPassword",
        "grant_type": "password"
    ]
    
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userData, options: .prettyPrinted) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(jsonData)
                
            } catch let error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: JSONSerialization => JSON vs "x-www-form-urlencoded". You are saying in your header that you will give the param using the url encoded form, and you send JSON. That's why. Also, note that POSTMAN can generate Swift Code. It's not beautiful code, but enough to spot issue/difference.

Comment: okay thanks for your comment, where exactly am i suppose to make the change in the code?

Comment: What change ? `request.httpBody = httpBody`, the `httpBody` you created is wrong. Fix that. What about checking the generate code from POSTMAN? And looking for "Swift URLEncoded Parameter" in your Search Engine didn't return anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720925/swift-4-send-post-request-as-x-www-form-urlencoded ? https://medium.com/@serge.works.io/swift-how-to-create-a-http-post-request-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-body-bfd9cd26d6d5 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063959/post-request-using-application-x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: httpBody has to be different for different "Content-Type". thank you for making me realise where i was going wrong.