# send data and image to PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass my data along with an image to php but it was throwing error `undefined index` my code is as follows

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="event" id="event" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="txtEName" id="txtEName" required/>
 <input type="text" name="txtEFree" required placeholder="(in minutes)"/>
 <input type="text" name="txtEFirstPay" required/>
 <input type="text" name="txtEFirstDuration" placeholder="(in minutes)"/>
 <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/> 
 <button type="button" id="saveEvent">SAVE</button>
</form
```

AJAX

```
 $("#saveEvent").on('click',(function() {
      var formData = new FormData($("#event"));
      $.ajax({
        url: "saveEvent.php", 
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData, 
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
          //further...
        }
      });
     }));
```

PHP

```
<?php
  require_once ("Php/db_connect.php");
  $name=$_REQUEST['txtEName'];
  echo var_dump($name);
  $free=$_REQUEST['txtEFree'];
  fpay=$_REQUEST['TxtEFirstPay'];
  $fduration=$_REQUEST['txtEFirstDuration'];
  $filename=$_FILES['filename']['name'];
  //upload code follows...
 ?>
```

When i try to `echo $name` its showing the error

> Notice: Undefined index: txtEName

what is the problem in this.
 anybody please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809937/undefined-index-with-post

Comment: `$name = $_POST['txtEName']`

Comment: echo var_dump is unnecessary. var_dump prints the output automatically

Comment: @ArmKh $_REQUEST will find either post or get variables, so that's not the issue

Comment: @Seena, you can not submit a form contains file via ajax, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: @lucumt the very link you've posted, in the accepted answer, has an edit which mentions that this is now possible, in most new browsers. That question is 8 years old, things have changed. Support starts from following desktop browsers versions. IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+